# react component callback method strategy

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning React and it seems like the convention is to use callback methods in your components. Which is great, but I'm wondering, for example, if you have a login component. What are the callbacks, or rather, the actual functionality of the component in this case?

You could have the component simply call a callback with the form data, or have it do the HTTP call and everything, and then call a callback with the result of that HTTP call.

I'm not sure how to decide on this.

Comment: Could you include some example code and what you've tried so far? What do you mean by callback methods in a component?

Comment: @squgeim I don't have a concrete code example, I mean, both work, I'm just wondering which is recommended in the mind of React. With callback methods I mean methods you pass along in the component props. These could be functions such as onLoginClicked that the component invokes, but are given by the parent component.

Comment: I’m not sure I fully understand your question, but it sounds like you’re wondering whether it’s better to have a Login component handle form submission events with its own class method (e.g. this.handleSubmit), or if it should use a callback (e.g. props.handleSubmit) passed in from a parent. Is that what you mean? If so, there is no “right” way. I’d suggest starting simple, though - if a class method that makes an HTTP request and then sets local component state based on the response will work for you, then don’t worry about making it more complex than that until you have a good reason to.

Comment: One of the biggest lessons I’ve learned in my never-ending React learning journey is that you shouldn’t feel pressured into a more complex structure because it seems “correct” or because you’re worried a simple/naive approach will come back to bite you later. An over-abstracted approach can come back to bite you just as hard (if not harder). It’s almost always better to start simple, and then only refactor to add the right abstractions once it becomes clear what they are.